# Add following list to site

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add the list that stores what the user is following to a site? I can't find it in the normal app/web parts ribbon on the edit page.

If this is not possible, does anyone know of a way to create a list that users can add documents they are following to that I can add to the page. The ist should only show the documents that the one user is following